# Can I randomly split the data with different seeds and average over the results for a robust estimate of accuracy?

Tags: validation, machine-learning

I have a query. I could find some papers that randomly divide the data set into train/test (70/30 or 90/10) at different seeds points (number of seeds: 10-15). It means for a given seed, they have a randomized selection of train/test data. The results are then averaged over the different seed points to get a robust estimate of accuracy. Is this an accepted way of doing cross-validation? (though technically it is not a 10-fold cross-validation). Thanks!

Comment: are there menioned any benefits over cv because i don't see them...

Comment: you can refer to this arXiv paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09850 where they have discussed that multiple randomized train/test splits with different seeds and averaging over the results gives a robust estimate. The work is yet to be published. Can we take this to granted to implement in our work?